# Adapt wrong date formats with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

[image]

I have a dataset with two date formats on a date column. Those with the time 12:00:00 AM are in the mm/dd format, and all the other ones are in the dd/mm format. I need all of them to be in the same format.

For example: line 9 needs to be 28/12/2020 and line 10 4/12/2021

I've tried to create a function using the length of the strings but could not get it right.

Comment: Are they actually strings, or have they been converted to dates?  This is a tricky tricky problem, because there are only TWO values there where the dd and mm order is obvious.

Comment: in the raw database they are strings, but when I try to convert in python using astype('datetime64') the ones in the different format get converted wrong. The only thing differentiating them is the '12:00:00 AM' time on the mm/dd format and the 00:00 on the dd/mm ones.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert them all to pandas datetime types.  You can truncate these to date types if the times are not important.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [
    ["02/09/2021 00:00"],
    ["4/14/2021 12:00:00 AM"],
    ["04/12/2021 00:00"],
    ["12/01/2020 00:00"],
    ["12/01/2020 00:00"],
    ["12/01/2020 00:00"],
    ["04/01/2021 00:00"],
    ["10/09/2020 00:00"],
    ["1/27/2021 12:00:00 AM"],
    ["12/28/2020 12:00:00 AM"],
    ["04/12/2021 00:00"]
]

def convert(d):
    if d[-1] == 'M':
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date'])
print(df)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(convert)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      Date
0         02/09/2021 00:00
1    4/14/2021 12:00:00 AM
2         04/12/2021 00:00
3         12/01/2020 00:00
4         12/01/2020 00:00
5         12/01/2020 00:00
6         04/01/2021 00:00
7         10/09/2020 00:00
8    1/27/2021 12:00:00 AM
9   12/28/2020 12:00:00 AM
10        04/12/2021 00:00
                  Date
0  2021-09-02 00:00:00
1  2021-04-14 12:00:00
2  2021-12-04 00:00:00
3  2020-01-12 00:00:00
4  2020-01-12 00:00:00
5  2020-01-12 00:00:00
6  2021-01-04 00:00:00
7  2020-09-10 00:00:00
8  2021-01-27 12:00:00
9  2020-12-28 12:00:00
10 2021-12-04 00:00:00
```